# removing an object from a control box

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, parent-child, disabled-control

I want to change the forecolor of radio buttons texts when the Group box Enabled property is set to false. The disabled color is so absurdly dark that you can't read the text in this state. I tried many things (like overriding the system default disabled color mode) without success.

I have no choice but to use this kind of controls, so I'm looking for a workaround. My idea was to superpose a lightly greyed label on the text, but this cause errors when initializing the control box.

I tried the following code to get the label out of the parent control box and avoid this problem:

```
RadioButtonLabel.Parent= Main_menu.Activeform;
```

I have no more errors, but the label now basically disappear in runtime.

Any solution?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: Can you not use the GroupBox.Enabled event.  Within that, if enabled then make radiobutton = somecolour, if not enable then someothercolour?

Comment: I actually use RadioButton.Enabled property. RadioButton.ForeColor property is overrided by the Enabled property

Answer (score 0):

instead of using dark color, try using this: (this is just an idea code)

```
if(groupbox.enable == false)
{
radiobutton.text = ""; //it means show nothing
}
else
{
radiobutton.text = "Whatever you like";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I am after. I need to prevent user options modifications but I would like them to be able to read the options they choosed in the previous stage. The sad thing is that read only option is only for text boxes, not for Radio buttons ...

Comment: @espressif you can enable it on or off?
I dont know exactly what your purpose is

Comment: The project is a 2 stages application for clinical purpose. The first allow parameters setting and the second consist of actually running the test, so the parameters are not user modifiables at this stage. Nonetheless, administrator can read the setting they made at the first stage.